# How to show targets available in a multi-stage Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Given a Dockerfile like

```
FROM nginx AS builder
COPY apps/service1/index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
COPY apps/service1/1MB.dat /usr/share/nginx/html/.

FROM builder AS debug
COPY apps/service1/status /usr/share/nginx/html/status

FROM builder AS test
COPY apps/service1/lulz /usr/share/nginx/html/lulz

FROM scratch AS runtime
COPY --from=builder /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html /idk.html
```

I want to get a list of the valid arguments to the `--target` flag. For example, to emit something like

```
builder
debug
test
runtime
```

Or alternatively, to answer the question of whether `$string` is a valid argument to target.

I know that for this particular Dockerfile, I could easily answer the question with grep. However, I don't control the Dockerfiles, and they might be arbitrarily ugly. Given that internally, docker (or kaniko, which is what I'm actually building with) checks the supplied target name against the available target names, it ought to be able to print those target names back.

THE ACTUAL USE CASE:

I get a lot of Dockerfiles from developers for services to be built. What I want to do is:

- Determine if the developer has specified a `test` stage.
- If so, build an image with `--target=test`, then run the resulting image & save its output somewhere
- Otherwise continue doing other CI workflow things without failing

In theory, this could be reduced to "Distinguish between failure to build an image due to the desired target not existing and an actual build failure." However, I don't want to do this. I'm using kaniko, which I think fewer people know than docker. Moreover, I don't know if I'm going to keep using kaniko forever, so even if kaniko does provide a way to easily distinguish between these two cases (I don't actually know), and even if I figured out what that is, I might have to move to another image builder, and then I would be constrained by having to figure out how to validate targets. Something which just introspected the Dockerfile & printed the available targets would be portable.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just perform the equivalent of `docker build --target test .`, and then on failure read stderr and look up `failed to reach build target test`.

Comment: As of my knowledge there is no easy way to just list all targets. You will probably need to parse the dockerfile yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with this:

```
sed -n 's/^FROM[[:space:]]\+[^ ]\+[[:space:]]\+AS[[:space:]]\+\([^ ]\+\)$/\1/p' Dockerfile
```

But I understand that having such a feature in "docker build" itself would be way better.